# selenium with chromedriver on centOS7 for spidering

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I trying to make Crawler for my server.

I Found chilkat Lib's CKSpider, but it is not support JS Rendering.

So I try to use selenium webdriver with Chrome.

I run with CentOS7, python2.7

I want spider all page with 1 baseDomain.

Example

```
BaseDomain = example.com
```

then find all page something like

```
example.com/event/.../../...
example.com/games/.../...
example.com/../.../..
...
```

My Crawler code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
chrome_driver_binary = "/root/chromedriver"

options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("lang=ko-KR,ko,en-US,en")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=options)
host = example.com

def Crawler(Url):   
    driver.get(Url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    #Do Something
    time.sleep(3)
    #Crawl next

Crawler(host)
driver.quit()
```

How can I crawl next page? Is there any other way in selenium

Or need other Lib for that?

Thanks for any Tips or Advice.